# How to convert code with promise to observable?

Tags: angular

I want to rewrite the code from promise to observable.

When I do this I get this error:

> this.options.upload(...).then is not a function

```
  embedFile(file: File, handlerId: string) {
    this.options.upload(file).then(
      (url) => {
        this.insertFileToEditor(url, handlerId);
        this.loading.removeAttribute('class');
        this.loading.setAttribute('class', Constants.NONE_DISPLAY_CLASS_NAME);
      },
      (error) => {
        this.loading.removeAttribute('class');
        this.loading.setAttribute('class', Constants.NONE_DISPLAY_CLASS_NAME);
        setTimeout(() => {
          const el = document.getElementById(handlerId);
          el.remove();
        }, 1000);
      }
    );
  }
```

This is my attempt to convert code from promise to observable:

```
  upload(image: File) {
    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('image', image, image.name);
    return this.http.post<PostInterface>(`${environment.url}/api/upload`, fd).pipe(
      tap((data) => {
        return of(`${environment.url}/static/${data?.imageUrl}`);
      })
    )
  }
```

Working code using promise:

```
  upload(image: File) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      const fd = new FormData();
      fd.append('image', image, image.name);
      try {
        const result = await this.http.post<PostInterface>(`${environment.url}/api/upload`, fd)
          .toPromise();
        return resolve(`${environment.url}/static/${result?.imageUrl}`);
      } catch (error) {
        reject('Upload failed');
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: tap does not return anything, it only creates a side effect. I think you are trying to use `map` instead. And instead of `this.options.upload(file).then` you should use `subscribe` instead

Answer (score 0):

`then` function can be replace with `map` function from `rxjs`,
and you can pass error callback as a second parameter of `subscribe`
check this example:

```
this.http.post<PostInterface>(`${environment.url}/api/upload`, 
     fd).pipe(
  map((data) => {
    return data.someManipulation());
  })
).subscribe(data => {
  // responsed data 
  // do something
},
err => {
  // handle error
})
```